# Nullables? Detecting them

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-2.0, nullable

Ok, im still a bit new to using nullable types.

I'm writing a reflecting object walker for a project of mine, im getting to the point where im setting the value of a reflected property with the value i've retrieved from a reflected property.

The value i've retrieved is still in `object` form, and it dawned on me, since i want my object walker to return null when it can't find something, (I thought about throwing an exception, but i want this to soft-fail when something's wrong).

Anyway, some of the values im setting/getting are `decimal` `bool` etc... so it dawned on me that i should just NOT set a non-nullable value, but I realized I straight up don't know how to tell `decimal` from `decimal?`

Is it enough to key on if the Type of the property im setting is inherited from `ValueType`?

Comment: I can't quite tell what you're asking, but you should know that an `object` will never be `int?` or `decimal?`. It will just be `null` if your `Nullable<>` doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code will tell you whether a type is nullable or not:

```
private bool IsNullableType(Type theType)
{
    return theType.IsGenericType && 
           theType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>));
}
```

Comment: How about "`return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(theType) != null;`" instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx):

> Nullable types are instances of the `System.Nullable<T>`  struct.